# Parsing JSON file in powershell with specific characters

Tags: json, powershell, parsing

I am trying to get the values in powershell within specific characters. Basically I have a json with thousands of objects like this

```
  "Name": "AllZones_APOPreface_GeographyMatch_FromBRE_ToSTR",
  "Sequence": 0,
  "Condition": "this.TripOriginLocationCode==\"BRE\"&&this.TripDestinationLocationCode==\"STR\"",
  "Action": "this.FeesRate=0.19m;this.ZoneCode=\"Zone1\";halt",
  "ElseAction": ""
```

I want everything within \"  \"

IE here I would see that BRE and STR is Zone1

All I need is those 3 things outputted.

I have been searching how to do it with ConvertFrom-Json but no success, maybe I just havent found a good article on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by representing your JSON as a string:

```
$myjson = @'
{
  "Name": "AllZones_APOPreface_GeographyMatch_FromBRE_ToSTR",
  "Sequence": 0,
  "Condition": "this.TripOriginLocationCode==\"BRE\"&&this.TripDestinationLocationCode==\"STR\"",
  "Action": "this.FeesRate=0.19m;this.ZoneCode=\"Zone1\";halt",
  "ElseAction": ""
}
'@
```

Next, create a regular expression that matches everything in between `\"` and `\"`, that's under 10 characters long (else it'll match unwanted results).

```
$regex = [regex]::new('\\"(?<content>.{1,10})\\"')
```

Next, perform the regular expression comparison, by calling the `Matches()` method on the regular expression. Pass your JSON string into the method parameters, as the text that you want to perform the comparison against.

```
$matchlist = $regex.Matches($myjson)
```

Finally, grab the `content` match group that was defined in the regular expression, and extract the values from it.

```
$matchlist.Groups.Where({ $PSItem.Name -eq 'content' }).Value
```

#### Result

```
BRE
STR
Zone1
```

#### Approach #2: Use Regex Look-behinds for more accurate matching

Here's a more specific regular expression that uses look-behinds to validate each field appropriately. Then we assign each match to a developer-friendly variable name.

```
$regex = [regex]::new('(?<=TripOriginLocationCode==\\")(?<OriginCode>\w+)|(?<=TripDestinationLocationCode==\\")(?<DestinationCode>\w+)|(?<=ZoneCode=\\")(?<ZoneCode>\w+)')
$matchlist = $regex.Matches($myjson)

### Assign each component to its own friendly variable name
$OriginCode, $DestinationCode, $ZoneCode = $matchlist[0].Value, $matchlist[1].Value, $matchlist[2].Value

### Construct a string from the individual components
'Your origin code is {0}, your destination code is {1}, and your zone code is {2}' -f $OriginCode, $DestinationCode, $ZoneCode
```

#### Result

```
Your origin code is BRE, your destination code is STR, and your zone code is Zone1
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. Ill try this out!